# replace image in div on scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

wanna replace the image in #logo with the image resized.png upon scroll down and on scroll up should return to normal.

tried with the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(this).scrollTop() > 100) $('#topbar, .cart-label').fadeOut('slow');
$('#logo').css({'background-image':'url(http://elementsmart.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/resized.png)','background-repeat':'no-repeat'})
if($(this).scrollTop() < 100) $('#logo, #topbar, .cart-label').fadeIn('fast');
})
});
```

resized.png does come on top but wanna replace it altogether and be restored upon scroll to top.
the link to the site is :http://elementsmart.com/product/deep-azure-rajasthani-necklace-set/
can sum1 suggest ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## UPDATE ANSWER

Check here, working DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/49HA3/1/

You are trying to give background-image wrongly to `a` tag, actually you need to change the src of `img` tag within `a` tag.

That is why, you got 2 images. One for `a` tag background-image, another is `img` within `a` tag.

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('#topbar, .cart-label').fadeOut('slow');
            $('#logo-img img')
                .css({'width':'184px','height':'33px'})
                .attr('src','http://elementsmart.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/resized.png');
        }
        if($(this).scrollTop() < 100) {
            $('#logo, #topbar, .cart-label').fadeIn('fast');
            $('#logo-img img')
                .css({'width':'184px','height':'60px'})    
                .attr('src','http://elementsmart.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/logo2.png');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: hey that worked perfectly thanx a lot ...... can u suugest some gud documentation for jquery ?